# How to display an image outside a window

Tags: python

I am trying to display an image on my desktop without any boarder or window, like an image floating in the desktop. I also want to be able to control its position once it has been created, with the arrow keys or with a line of code that changes its position with some coordinate system of some sorts. I haven't found any method after some reaserch (not in Python, at least).

If that's not possible, please recommend another programming language that can.

Comment: That's likely a function of your desktop environment and the library you're using to interact with it, not language itself.

Comment: I mean I get what you're saying, but as far as I know Python can interact with almost anything, provided that you have the right libraries and such. I'm looking for those, and an explanation of their usage of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Tkinter` for this.
I made a little example:

Python3

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, Tk, Label, PhotoImage

win = Tk()

win.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
win.iconify()

window = Toplevel(win)
window.geometry("500x500+100+100")
window.overrideredirect(1)

photo = PhotoImage(file="test.png")

label = Label(window, image=photo)
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Python2

```
from Tkinter import Toplevel, Tk, Label
import ImageTk

win = Tk()

win.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
win.iconify()

window = Toplevel(win)
window.geometry("500x500+100+100") # create an window 500x500 pixel, 100 pixels from the upper left corner
window.overrideredirect(1)         # Take the border away

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="test.png")

label = Label(window, image=photo)
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: K nevermind got it to work with Pillow. I'll give you your thumbs up

Comment: Thanks dude! One last thing: Is there any way to make the background transparent? That would really help. Thanks for the Python3 update, really helped as well